# Group/Fix by string then match distinct values

Tags: tableau-api

I have some data like so (last column represents the Boolean output I want):

```
Sample  index  date         Result
base    1      29/11/2016   True
base    1      29/11/2016   True
base    2      29/11/2016   False
base    3      30/11/2016   True
base    4      30/11/2016   False
test    1      29/11/2016   True
test    3      30/11/2016   True
test    4      29/11/2016   False
```

The 'result' needs to show whether base and test share an index value on the same date.

Explaining above:

1. Index 1 has two occurrences for Base and one for Test - thus True
2. Index 2 has only one occurrence for Base, none for Test - thus False
       (even if there were two for Base it would still be False)
3. Index 3 has one for Base and one for Test - thus True
4. Index 4 has one for Base and one for Test BUT they are different
       dates - thus False.

I have been fiddling with LOD queries but I cannot make heads or tails of it even though it seems SO simple. I have been staring at it too long, can anyone help please?

Solution: As per Alex's answer I am using the following to get the bool output. Index is a whole number dimension, date is date dimensions and Sample is string dimension.

```
{FIXED [Index],[Date]:MAX([Sample]="Base") AND max([Sample] = "Test")}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
{ fixed index, date : max(Sample = "base) and max(Sample = "test") }
```

I'm not able to test at the moment, but think of this as creating a temporary table showing FOR EACH index and date pair, whether or not there is at least one record with Sample="base" and one record with Sample="test"

If your only dimensions on the viz are index and date, you can simplify by using an aggregate calculation instead of an LOD calculation -- i.e. remove everything up before and up to the colon, and drop the trailing }

Comment: Works wonders! Much better than my LOD attempt fixing on sample and date then trying index to begin with. Cheers

Comment: Tried this fix and I am getting an error "max is being called with(boolean), did you mean (float). @AMcNall Could you paste your final calculated field that you have working now? Thanks

Comment: I used pretty much exactly what Alex posted, I will update the main post with the calculated field code

Comment: Thanks @AMcNall. Still not working for me?? checked the data types and pasted your code. Maybe its a version issue? working off tableau 9.0.3

Comment: Good thought @lampbob, I am working on 10.0.1. I had a look through the patch notes but didnt spot anything directly related to the error you are getting but it looks like the newer version supports MAX aggregations on bool types now!

Comment: Max() and Min() only started supporting Booleans in version 9.2. True is greater than False. So max(condition) is true when ANY row satisfies the condition and min(condition) is true when EVERY row satisfies the condition.

Comment: There is a complication if your condition evaluates to null for any of your data rows. In that case, I recommend wrapping your condition in a call to ifnull(), like ifnull(condition, false)

Comment: @lampbob, you need version 9.2 to use min() and max() with booleans. otherwise you can use count(if <condition> then 1 end) > 0 instead of max(<condition>)

Comment: @AlexBlakemore Thanks